# Window resizing problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When  i resize my window popup stays at center position. It show adjust depending on the window size. Whats wrong in my code

```
.Popup
        {

            display: none;
            height: 400px;
            width: 400px;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        onload = function () {
            var height = "innerHeight" in window
               ? window.innerHeight
               : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
            $('#popup').css({
                'margin-top': (height / 2) - (200),
                'margin-left': (document.body.offsetWidth / 2) - (200)
            });

            document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "inline";
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the popup to remain centered with respect to the window, you need to use negative margins and percentage-based positioning.

Also, your CSS references a class named `.Popup` and your JavaScript an ID named `#popup`. You may want to sort that out. Here is some example CSS:

```
.Popup
{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Note that the margins are half of the respective dimensions. The JavaScript is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're setting constant pixel values for the height and the width.  So for example if my browser window is 1000 pixels wide onload then you set margin-left to 300px.  This constant value is preserved when you resize the window.  You probably instead want to work with percentage values and ditch the javascript.  For example,

```
#popup
{
     display: none;
     height: 400px;
     width: 400px;
     margin-top: 50%
     margin-left: 50%
     position: fixed;
     background-color: white;
     z-index: 9999;
 }
```